# Gamemaker Zooming and Dragging

Tags: object, view, game-maker, gml

I am currently using gamemaker to create a floorplan system. I am able to zoom into a room, drag and zoom out but how can i limit how much i can zoom in and out? The size of the room is 1024  by 768 px. I want to be able to zoom out to the way it originally looks when you first enter the room.

This is my code currently which i have placed in the script:

```
X=view_xview[0];
Y=view_yview[0];
if mouse_check_button(mb_left){
global.DRAG=true;
window_set_cursor(cr_drag);
view_xview-=vmx;
view_yview-=vmy;
}

/*else{
if !keyboard_check(vk_space){
    global.DRAG=false
}
window_set_cursor(cr_default);
}
*/
vmx=(mouse_x-X)-omx;
omx=(mouse_x-X);
vmy=(mouse_y-Y)-omy;
omy=(mouse_y-Y);

if mouse_wheel_up(){
center_of_space_x=view_xview+view_wview/2;
center_of_space_y=view_yview+view_hview/2;
view_wview-=view_wview*0.15;
view_hview-=view_hview*0.15;
view_xview=center_of_space_x-view_wview/2;
view_yview=center_of_space_y-view_hview/2;

}
if mouse_wheel_down(){
center_of_space_x=view_xview+view_wview/2;
center_of_space_y=view_yview+view_hview/2;
view_wview+=view_wview*0.15;
view_hview+=view_hview*0.15;
view_xview=center_of_space_x-view_wview/2;
view_yview=center_of_space_y-view_hview/2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this is fairly simple, using the [`clamp function`](https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/maths/real%20valued%20functions/clamp.html). A modified version of your code would look like this:

```
view_wview = clamp(view_wview * 0.15, min_size, 1024)
view_hview = clamp(view_hview * 0.15, min_size, 768)
```

Comment: Hello Duphus, 
Thank you for the reply, I tried using the lines of code you provided but recieved the following error: 
FATAL ERROR in
action number 1
of  Step Event0
for object control:

Variable obj_FCH.min_size(100010, -2147483648) not set before reading it.
 at gml_Script_drag_and_zoom (line 27) -     view_wview = clamp(view_wview * 0.15, min_size, 1024)

stack frame is
gml_Script_drag_and_zoom (line 27)
called from - gml_Object_control_StepNormalEvent_1 (line 3) - drag_and_zoom();

Comment: Where do i declare the min_size and what do i declare it as because it is not a game maker function.

Comment: @Jivvy Sorry, I didn't mean that min_size would be a variable. I meant that you would replace it with what you want the min size to be. For example, if you wanted the minimum size to be 44 for each of them, you would put this: view_wview = clamp(view_wview * 0.15, 44, 1024); Though I would replace 44 with a number that better fits into game/application.

Comment: The clamp function doesn't seem to work. It is not limiting the view :(. I have adjusted the min size multiple times to test it.

Answer (score 0):

simply use the [clamp](https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/maths/real%20valued%20functions/clamp.html) function to limit the view_wview and view_hview

```
var maxZoomIn = 0.2; //500% zoom in limit
var maxZoomOut = 1; //100% zoom out limit
if mouse_wheel_up(){
    center_of_space_x=view_xview+view_wview/2;
    center_of_space_y=view_yview+view_hview/2;
    view_wview = clamp(view_wview - view_wview * 0.15, maxZoomIn*room_width, maxZoomOut*room_width)
    view_hview = clamp(view_hview - view_hview * 0.15, maxZoomIn*room_height, maxZoomOut*room_height)
    view_xview=center_of_space_x-view_wview/2;
    view_yview=center_of_space_y-view_hview/2;
}
```

and similar for mouse_wheel_down.